# Prove that if $F\circ F$ is contractive , then F has a unique fix point

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Let F:$X \rightarrow X$ where X is $\mathbb{R} ^n$(or a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$). Prove that if $F\circ F: X \rightarrow X $ is contractive, then F has a unique fixed point.

My attempt: Firstly, I tried direct prove but without much success.

So,I switched to prove by contradiction which I found I almost get it,

Assume there is no fix point for F , i.e. $F(w)\neq w $ for all w, apply F, we have $F(F(w))\neq F(w)$ , but $F(w)\neq w $ from the previos , so $F(F(w))\neq w $ for all w which contradicts $F\circ F$ have a fix point because $F\circ F$ is guarantee to have a fix point as it is contractive.

However, I notice that $F(w)\neq w $ does not imply $F(F(w)) \neq F(w)$ because the function may not be 1-1 , and I am stucked.

I also wonder if X is $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in fact useful in somewhere of the prove or not.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is relevant because it's complete. What is the relation between fixed points of $F$ and fixed points of $F\circ F$?

Comment: They should be the same because if F have fix point, say p ,than $F(p)=p$ and apply F again we have $F(F(p))=F(p)=p$
But the question did not assume F have a fix point, this is in fact what we need to prove.

Comment: That shows the inclusion in one direction. In general, $f\circ f$ can have more fixed points than $f$. But we know that we must look among the fixed points of $F\circ F$, nothing else could be a fixed point of $F$. What do we know about fixed points of $F\circ F$?

Comment: As $F\circ F$ is contractive, it have a unique fix point by the contractive mapping theorem.

Comment: Right. So we need to see that that is already a fixed point of $F$. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: No, is $X=\mathbb{R} ^n$ needed to be used here?  Or is it something really trivial but just I did not see it?

Comment: We need that $X$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to guarantee that $F\circ F$ has a fixed point (Banach's fixed point theorem). If $X$ is not complete, the point that should be a fixed point of the contraction might be missing. Now, let $x_0$ be the fixed point of $F\circ F$. You want to see that $F(x_0) = x_0$. What is the characterisation of $x_0$ that you know?

Comment: I know that $F(F(x_0)) =x_0$

Comment: And you know that $F(F(y)) = y \implies y = x_0$. You want to show $F(x_0) = x_0$, so what can you try next?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest. Apply $F^{-1}$ to both sides?

Comment: You don't know that $F^{-1}$ exists (it usually won't). All you have are $F$ and $F\circ F$.

Comment: Using prove by contradiction or something?

Comment: Thank you. I have ask my professor finally. The answer is to consider$F\circ F \circ F$ and view it at 2 different viewpoints. I was so close!!! Thank you anyway, Daniel.

Comment: Right, $(F\circ F)(F(x_0)) = F((F\circ F)(x_0) = F(x_0)$, whence $F(x_0) = x_0$ by the uniqueness of the fixed point of $F\circ F$.